# using DeleteCases to delete vectors with particular index as 0

Tags: matrix, vector, column, filtering

Assume I have a set of vectors

```
  set = {{0,1,1,0,1}, {1,0,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1,0}}.
```

I want to delete the vectors which have the last entry as 0. In the above example, it is the 3rd and 4th vectors.

Can I use DeleteCases in a better way than following?

```
 Do[If[set[[j]][[5]] == 0, set[[j]] = ConstantArray[0, Length[set[[1]]]]], 
 {j, 1, Length[set]}];

 set =  DeleteCases[set, ConstantArray[0, Length[set[[1]]]]];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[set, {___, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

In this case [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) also works:

```
Pick[set, Last /@ set, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

---

You asked about positions other than last.  It is possible to generate a working pattern using [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), e.g. `{_, _, 0, _, _}`, and this process can be automated, but that is not usually the first approach I would recommend.

You can use individual part extraction in either [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) or [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)/[`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html), or you can create a "mask" for use with `Pick` as I showed above.  Notable differences are that `Select` only operates at a single level, while `Cases` and `Pick` generalize to deeper structures.  `Pick` is often somewhat faster than other methods, especially if one uses fast numeric functions where possible.

Picking according to the second column:

```
Pick[set, set[[All, 2]], 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}}
> ```

Suppose however that your keep elements are not all the same, like `1` in this example above:

```
set2 = {{3, 1, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 0, 0, 1}, {3, 1, 0, 4, 4}};

Pick[set2, Unitize @ set2[[All, 3]], 1]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 2, 4}}
> ```

Note here that [`Unitize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html) is needed to make all keep elements into `1`.  While it is possible to use e.g. [`Positive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Positive.html) instead this is not as efficient because in *Mathematica* Booleans [`True`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True.html) and [`False`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False.html) cannot be [packed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/121), while machine-size integers can.  It is for this reason that I *do not* recommend these apparent equivalents:

```
(* Not recommended where performance matters *)

Pick[set2, Positive @ set2[[All, 3]]]

Pick[set2, set2[[All, 3]], _?Positive]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you modify this to any index instead of just the last one?

Comment: @cleanplay Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Wizard, thanks again. Can I use Pick over multiple indices in the columns of set. For example, to find vectors with both 2nd and 3rd index as 1, I tried        
Pick[set, set[[All, 2 ;; 3]], {1, 1}]  but that doesn't recognize the pattern in the last argument

Answer (score 6):

Or...

```
Select[set, Last[#] != 0 &]
```

or...

```
Select[set, #[[-1]] != 0 &]
```

or...

```
DeleteCases[set, x_ /; Last[x] == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `Delete` in conjunction with `Position`:

```
Delete[set, Position[set[[All, -1]], 0]]
```

If I cared about speed for long lists, I'd probably use

```
Delete[set, Partition[Random`Private`PositionsOf[set[[All, -1]], 0], 1]]
```

Comment: In version 10.1 under Windows x64 your `PositionsOf` code is significantly slower than `Pick`, at least the way I tested it, e.g. `set = RandomInteger[3, {1*^6, 5}]`.  Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now that you say it, it becomes clear to me that `Pick` should be faster. OP asked for using `DeleteCases` which sort of drove me to using `Delete`. But significance lies somewhat in the eye of the beholder. On my Haswell QuadCore with _Mathematica_ 11.3 under macOS, `Delete[set, Partition[Random`Private`PositionsOf[set[[All, -1]], 0], 1]]` requires `0.030` seconds while `Pick[set, set[[All, -1]], 1]` needs only `0.022`. This difference is really small if you compare the timings to the timings of pattern-matching based methods.